# How can I check Rails record caching in unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, caching

I'm trying to make a unit test to ensure that certain operations do / do not query the database.  Is there some way I can watch for queries, or some counter I can check at the very worst?

Comment: Are you trying to test rails' caching, or do you have a bunch of custom SQL you are trying to cache manually?

Comment: Rails' caching.  Specifically, I have a couple functions that attempt to use cached data intelligently (x.loaded? checks), and want to exercise both code paths reliably, *and* make sure they're not still hitting the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to discern whether or not Rails (ActiveRecord) actually caches queries, you don't have to write a unit test for those - they [already exist](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/query_cache_test.rb) and are part of Rails itself.

**Edit:**

In that case, I would probably see if I could adapt one of the strategies the rails team uses to test ActiveRecord itself.  Check the following test from my link above:

```
def test_middleware_caches
  mw = ActiveRecord::QueryCache.new lambda { |env|
    Task.find 1
    Task.find 1
    assert_equal 1, ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.length
  }
  mw.call({})
end
```

You may be able to do something like the following:

```
def check_number_of_queries
  mw = ActiveRecord::QueryCache.new lambda { |env|
    # Assuming this object is set up to perform all its operations already
    MyObject.first.do_something_and_perform_side_operations
    puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.length.to_s
  }
end
```

I haven't tried such a thing, but it might be worth investigating further.  If the above actually does return the number of cached queries waiting to happen, it should be trivial to change the puts to an assert for your test case.

Comment: My intent is to discern whether or not a single top-level operation communicates with the database efficiently.  If I "x.do_something_and_perform_side_operations_like_emailing_and_a_dozen_other_things", I would like to be able to tell if it fires off 10 queries or 10,000 without reading logs.

Comment: Yeah, I started looking through, and found their "ActiveRecord::SQLCounter" class.  They're capturing logging info (before writing, they're not actually grepping the log, but still).  Nuttery.  Thanks for the link + extra infos!